# A specific problem about composition of functions

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)= \dfrac{1+10x}{10-100x}$ is given.

And also $ f^n =\underbrace{f\circ f\circ f \circ\cdots \circ f}_{n}$ is given.

Find the sum $f(1/2)+f^2(1/2)+f^3(1/2)+\cdots +f^{6000}(1/2)$

After a few operations I supposed to have a generalization but I could not

generalize...

Comment: Did you try writing out $f^{(n)}(\frac 12)$ for, say, $n=1$ to $10$?

Comment: I tried $n=1$ to $3$. but I could not find a relation...

Comment: That's not very far.  Go out a few more.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\{f^n(1/2)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is periodic.